# Months list between 2 dates in Laravel Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am a beginner in Laravel. I have Laravel 5.8 in my project.

I have 2 dates: `2019-01-01` and `2019-10-14`.

I would like to display a list of months with information on the number of days a given month has.

How to do it?

```
$period = CarbonPeriod::create('2019-01-01', '2019-10-14');
```

??

And what's next?

Answer (score 0):

`month()` function will set the unit interval for the period object, which is `month` for your case.

```php
$period = CarbonPeriod::create('2019-01-01', '2019-10-14')->month();

$months = collect($period)->map(function (Carbon $date) {
    return [
        'month' => $date->month,
        'name' => $date->monthName,
        'days' => $date->daysInMonth,
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$period = CarbonPeriod::create('2019-01-01', '2019-10-14')->month();
$months = collect($period)->map(function (Carbon $date) {
   return  $date->monthName;
})->toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.